# Should I apply normalization to predicted probabilities from 7 different models before computing correlation among them?

Tags: correlation, standard-deviation, normalization, ensemble-learning

I'd like to check if there are correlation among predicted probabilities of models in a voting classifier. According to the table below, one of models, Model5, has mean 40.9% and standard deviation 46.29% which is prominently different from that of other models. My Question is that since the predicted probabilities already lie in the range between 0 and 1, despite the difference between that of model5 and other models  ,should I  normalize the probabilities of models before computing correlation matrix?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "mean" of Model 5 is, unless 40.9 is just the predicted probability.  If that's the case, then as you suspected, the predicted probabilities are already on the same scale, so no need to "normalize."

Comment: hi, thank you for your replying and my apologies for letting you confused. Yes. The mean is an average of predicted probabilities similar to the ones derived from sklearn model method "predict_prob".

Comment: hi StatsStudent, I'm wondering as long as features are on the same scale, then I don't need to scale them even though their mean and standard deviation are extremely different  ?

Comment: They are different because they have different predictive probabilities.  You wouldn't want to scale them since they are already on the same scale and therefore directly comparable.

Comment: Hi StatsStudent, thanks for your clear explanation. Really appreciate.

Comment: I'll go ahead and turn this into an official answer so you can accept it, if you found the answer helpful.

Comment: Normalize how? Scaling the values from each method by a linear factor will change absolutely nothing about the correlations between the methods, and Spearman correlations with be unchanged by any monotonic mapping at all. The correlation between two variables does not depend on the scale of either.

Comment: hi Nuclear Hoagie, thank you for your replying. How about statistical test like t-test and k-s test ? Are they vulnerable to normalization?

Comment: A t-test is an entirely different topic. I'd suggest you open a new question if you want to discuss.  In order to carry out t-tests, you have to standardize your observations.  This is necessary part of the test.

Comment: Hi  StatsStudent, thank you for your replying and suggention. I will open a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not need to scale the predicted probabilities, since, as you were correctly thinking, the predicted probabilities, by definition, are already on the same scale between 0 and 1.  The "large" difference you see in predicted probabilities are simply just large differences you see in the model performance.